# How will i style wordpress custom menu page of plugins when developing a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress plugin development. My question is about custom back-end menu for plugin.Now I am using inline style for this menu pages(admin.php). How'll I add a stylesheet for it?
Code syntax of this question is as below

```
add_menu_page('File Manager Settings Page', 'File Manager', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'plugin_main_menu', plugins_url('/images/wp-icon.png', __FILE__));
add_submenu_page(__FILE__, 'Add File', 'Add File', 'manage_options', __FILE__ . 'add_file', add_file);
function plugin_main_menu() {
    //code for main menu.This take admin.php template.
    // How'll I style this part?
 }
```

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**try this**

```
function loadscript()
{
     wp_enqueue_style('my-style',  WP_CONTENT_URL . '/plugins/pluginname/css/mycss.css');

      wp_enqueue_style('my-style',  WP_CONTENT_URL . '/themes/themename/css/mycss.css');

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','loadscript');
```

Comment: Thanks. I used like this outside plugin_main_menu(). Now it works...  `code`function loadscript()
{
     wp_enqueue_style('my-style',  WP_CONTENT_URL . '/plugins/file-manager/css/plugin-style.css');
}add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','loadscript');`code`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:

```
wp_enqueue_style($handle, $src, $deps, $ver);
```

This is insert the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/themename/styles/mystyle.css">
```

Of course that was just an example, you need to add the correct path to the `$src` and to other parameters..

Check the [manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).

Answer (score -1):

On success, `add_menu_page()` and `add_submenu_page()` return a hook name, which you can use with the dynamic `load-{$page}` action hook ([link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-(page))). Example:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'so27619539_admin_menu' );
function so27619539_admin_menu()
{
    $fmsp = add_menu_page( 'File Manager Settings Page', 'File Manager', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'plugin_main_menu', plugins_url( '/images/wp-icon.png', __FILE__ ) );

    add_action( "load-$fmsp", "so27619539_admin_styles" );
}

function so27619539_admin_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'so27619539' );
}
```